# Nestjs authentication does not work in docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, nestjs, nrwl-nx, nestjs-passport

I developed an full stack app using Angular as the frontend and Nestjs as the backend. The project is organized in a monorepository with NX. The project works fine on my local machine, including authentication (Passport library from Nestjs).

So I decided to dockerize the app, but when the app is run in the docker container the protected routes from the Nestjs backend are not accessible and I am getting a 401 error despite using the JWT token that I got from the same instance running in the docker container.

I migrated the project from bcrypt to bcryptjs because I was getting an error when building the docker container. The thing that confuses me mostly is that on my local machine everything works fine, but in the docker container the protected routes are not accessible despite using the JWT token that I got from the backend.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14
ENV PORT=3333
WORKDIR /app
COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "npm-shrinkwrap.json*","nx.json", "./"]
RUN npm install 
COPY ./apps .
EXPOSE 3333
CMD npm start
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  myapp:
    image: myapp
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      API_PORT: 3333
      JWT_SECRET: verystrongsecret
      JWT_EXPIRES_IN: 3600
      DB_TYPE: postgres
      DB_PORT: 5432
      DB_HOST: postgres
      DB_USERNAME: user
      DB_PASSWORD: password
      DB_NAME: db
      NODE_ENV: development
      TYPEORM_SYNC: 'true'
    ports:
      - 3333:3333

  postgres:
    image: postgres:10.4
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: db
```

How to solve the issue with the authentication? What could cause docker to this strange behavior?

JwtStrategy:

```
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(UserRepository) private userRepository: UserRepository
  ) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      secretOrKey: process.env.JWT_SECRET || config.get('jwt.secret'),
    });
  }

  async validate(payload: JwtPayload): Promise<User> {
    const { email } = payload;
    const user = await this.userRepository.findOne({ email });

    if (!user) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }

    return user;
  }
}
```

to protect the routes I am using the : `@UseGuards(AuthGuard())`
where `AuthGuard` is from the passport library.

The AuthModule:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' }),
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET || jwtConfig.secret,
      signOptions: {
        expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN || jwtConfig.expiresIn,
      },
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserRepository]),
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService, JwtStrategy],
  exports: [AuthService, JwtStrategy, PassportModule],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

Comment: Could you post the exact error you're getting? And did you try to call the login endpoint from the postman, and get the token, and then try hitting the API in a different endpoint with that token (using Postman)?

Comment: The problem is that I am not getting any errors. I am calling the login route and from there I am getting the access token. Then I append the access token to the header "Authorization" => "Bearer {token}" of a request, and then I am trying to hit a protected route but the server response is an 401 error. When I run the code locally on my machine everything works fine. I tried to remove the guards from the routes and everything worked fine then (in the docker container).

Comment: Can you put the implementation of your Guard?

Comment: Can you put logs inside `validate` function to log `payload`, and `user`. Then could you also show the place where you have the JWT token generation logic for login? Just wanted to make sure, you're using the same secret at both the places.

Comment: When I run it locally the validate method has logged the user, password and salt. But in the docker container there was no output at all. I added the AuthModule which registers the jwt secret. I mean did I put the env variables in the docker container wrong? I have no idea why this is not working in the container but works locally.

Comment: If you put a `console.log` inside `validate` method, you should be able to see the log in the container logs, right? You can see the logs if you run the docker-compose file without `-d`. Or you can use `docker logs --follow <CONTAINER_NAME_OF_YOUR_MY_APP>`

Comment: Yes right. The only method that shows an output is the sign in method which logs the email. Thank you for your patients.

Comment: So, can you try to put `console.log`s for `payload` and `user` now? Then they will be shown in container logs as well

Comment: I did that, but as I said, when I locally run the code I get the email, password, salt logged, but in the container not. It seems that in the container the validate method is not being called.

Comment: Can you also log the ‘jwtFromRequest’ and ‘secretOrKey’ values in JwtStrategy constructor? I think those values could be invalid. You need to log them before calling super constructor

Comment: I have put the console.log in the constructor but none of the values have been logged. I will try to put a hardcoded jwt secret and try it.

Comment: Yep the jwt secret was logged but I did not see it, it is the same as the env variable. 

It also does not work with the hardcoded jwt secret. I don't know where to look anymore. I will implement the authentication from scratch again. Thank you very much for your help!